# Different Color Links on the Same HTML Page

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink

Hi I am trying to have different color links on the same page. I want some links to be blue and some links to be black. I am new to html and CSS so thank you in advance!

-Spencer

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**CSS**:

```
a.class1 {color:red;}
a.class1:link  {text-decoration: none; color: red;}
a.class1:visited {text-decoration: none; color: red;}
a.class1:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: red;}
a.class1:active {text-decoration: none; color: red;}


a.class2 {color:blue;}
a.class2:link {text-decoration: none; color: blue;}
a.class2:visited {text-decoration: none; color: blue;}
a.class2:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: blue;}
a.class2:active {text-decoration: none; color: blue;}
```

**HTML**:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="class1">Google</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" class="class2">Stackoverflow</a>
```

**Demo**:
https://jsfiddle.net/3L4xguj7/

**Update 16.05.2021:**
Updated link

Comment: This won't work, you have to write `a.class1:link`, `a.class1:visited`, etc.

Comment: `a:active` must below `a:hover` to be effective. see a different http://jsfiddle.net/huhu/4qbFe/1/

Comment: plus one for `A.class2:hover`

Comment: Its a.class1:link guys - maybe the change that @sv88erik got reverted. Careful ya !

Answer (score 5):

just set a class name to ur hyper links `<a>` and write the CSS according to ur requirement

for Example

**CSS**

```
<style>
.red { 
 color : #f00; text-decoration : none;
}

.green { 
 color : #0f0; text-decoration : none;
}

.blue { 
 color : #00f; text-decoration : none;
}

</style>
```

**Markup** :

```
<a href="#" class="red" > Link0 </a>
<a href="#" class="green" > Link1 </a>
<a href="#" class="blue" > Link2 </a>
```

### [A simple Demo](http://jsbin.com/ekumu3)

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. However, the new classes don't have some of the effects that I need, like being underlined when they are hovered over. How would I extend these CSS things as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can give the links different classes like:

```
<a href="..." class="internal">Link to some internal page</a>
<a href="..." class="external">Link to some external page</a>
```

And write CSS rules like:

```
a.internal {
    color: ...;
}

a.external {
    color: ...;
}
```

`a.internal` means *select all `a`-elements with class `internal`*.

[Learn more about CSS.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS)

Comment: Since there are only two different colors - blue and black - there is no need for two classes. One color can be the default one (which blue is anyway), and the other color can be a class.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://" style="color: red">RED</a>

<a href="http://" style="color: blue">RED</a>
```

As seen above, you simply input style="color: ###" in the a href to set it to whatever you want if you wish to set each individual link. :)

For more general, use

```
<a href="http://" class="red">RED</a>

<a href="http://" class="blue">RED</a>
```

and in your CSS file state

```
.red {
color: red;
}

.blue {
color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to specify which links should have which style, and there are seveal to choose from. Some examples:

All links that is within the element with `id="Main"` are black:

```
#Main a { color: #000; }
```

All links that is within any element with `class="Message"` are blue:

```
.Message a { color: #00f; }
```

All links that themselves have `class="command"` are black:

```
a.command { color: #000; }
```

All links that are within a `li` element are dark blue:

```
li a { color: #009; }
```

You can also specify style directly for a specific link.

```
<a href="page.html" style="color:#000;">
```

Comment: any reason why only `a.Message` works and `.Message a` doesn't?  Is this browser dependent?

Comment: @BrianWiley: They match different elements. `a.Message` matches links with `class="Message"`, while `.Message a` matches links within an element with `class="Message`.