# Two-colored link that switches the colors upon mouse hovering

Tags: html, hyperlink

How can I create a two-colored link that switches the colors when the mouse hovers over the text?

The result should behave like this:

[image: link that switches colors upon mouse hover]

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531233/11826257, I tried the solution below. But it only re-colors the word over which the mouse hovers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      span.red_to_blue{color:red;}
      span.red_to_blue:hover{color:blue;}
      span.blue_to_red{color:blue;}
      span.blue_to_red:hover{color:red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="red_to_blue">Hello</span>
      <span class="blue_to_red">World</span>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use `a:hover .red_to_blue {}`, and same for the second span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from CBroe contains the solution: You can use a:hover followed by a [CSS class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). It is thus possible to define different behaviors for different classes. The classes can then be referred to in the html code, for example within a span element. The remodeled code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .red_to_blue{color:red;}
      .blue_to_red{color:blue;}
      a:hover .red_to_blue{color:blue;}
      a:hover .blue_to_red{color:red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="red_to_blue">Hello</span>
      <span class="blue_to_red">World</span>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting `SPAN` within `SPAN`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      span.red_to_blue{color:red;}
      span.red_to_blue:hover{color:blue;}
      span.blue_to_red{color:blue;}
      span.blue_to_red:hover{color:red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="red_to_blue">Hello<span class="blue_to_red">World</span></span>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hovering over the word "world" will switch the color of both words, as desired. Hovering over "hello" will change the color of "hello" but not the one of "world". So not a solution in this particular case but still interesting to see that you can nest span elements. Thanks.